# How can I find the closest vector3 to a given target vector among all vectors orthogonal to a given input vector3?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, math, vector

Suppose I have two input vectors with nonzero magnitudes:

```
Vector3 t;
Vector3 o;
```

I need to find the normalized vector `v` such that out of all normalized vectors that are orthogonal to `o`, `v` is the one that is closest to this `t` "target" vector. I also need to know if `t` and `o` are colinear in which case no one such single `v` exists.

Illustration of this relationship:

[image]

For a concrete example, suppose I have a game where the player will occasionally see a certain compass-like object on a surface in the environment. The player will have to point the needle on this compass towards a pictured object that was placed randomly somewhere in the game world. When the player selects the needle's position, I need to know how far off the player's selection is from the "true" direction of the object.

The compass needle is fixed to rotate around an axis with world direction `o` (perhaps this is the compass's `transform.forward`), and the direction of the pictured game object is `t`.

When `t` and `o` are not orthogonal, the compass needle will not be able to point directly in `t`, so I want to know: **How can I get the closest possible direction the compass needle can point at, which is `v`?** This way, I can measure the angle between this goal direction and the player's selected direction. And, when that angle is below some threshold, the player is successful.

Comment: This sounds more suitable for [Maths](https://math.stackexchange.com) since the actual implementation seems to be very secondary

Comment: @derHugo [As far as I can tell](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/300689/are-questions-asking-for-a-mathematical-formula-on-topic/300761#300761), questions asking about how to implement a solution (even if the solution is math-based) are on-topic.

Comment: well the linked question was strongly downvoted and closed as too broad ;) Honestly if you wouldn't have already answered I would have suggested to move it since it is primarily about understanding the maths behind it .. also note the [other answer](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/300763/7111561) .. the implementation in Unity is then very trivial since the methods are called exactly like the mathematical construct behind the solution. This seems more to be in general a question about how the cross product works which I would say is a pure maths question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use vector cross products to solve for this. Note that the order of the parameters of `Vector3.Cross` matters--inconsistently ordering the parameters can produce unexpected results.

1. Take the cross product of `t` and `o`.

   ```
   Vector3 x = Vector3.Cross(t, o);
   ```
2. If `o` and `t` are colinear, `x` will be equal to `Vector3.zero`.

   ```
   if (x == Vector3.zero) 
   {
       // Handle colinear situation
   }
   ```
3. Otherwise, `x` will be a vector that is orthogonal to both `o` and `t` and  therefore also orthogonal to `v`:

   ```
   else
   {
   ```
4. Now that we have two vectors that are orthogonal to `v` (that is, `o` and `x`), we can do another cross product to find a vector that is colinear with `v`. And if we are careful about the ordering of this second cross product compared to the cross product we used to calculate `x`, the output of the second cross product will point in the same direction as `v` as well. All that is then left is to normalize it:

   ```
       Vector3 v = Vector3.Cross(o, x).normalized;

       // Use v
   }
   ```

Altogether:

```
Vector3 x = Vector3.Cross(t, o);

if (x == Vector3.zero) 
{
    // Handle colinear situation
}
else
{
    Vector3 v = Vector3.Cross(o, x).normalized;

    // Use v
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Let me put simple way how to solve it.

Vectors orthogonal to `o` and sharing the same start point, and, for simplicity, having the same length as `t` fill the the orthogonal circle at the `o` start point. Suppose you find one, you could rotate it around `o` by some angle and it would still be orthogonal.

So now you have vector `v` and quest is for rotation angle to find. After rotation angle is found you got yourself an answer

Write equation for distance between `v` and `t` depending on rotation angle. Minimizing this distance - either numerically, or analytically doing derivatives and assigning them to 0 would provide you with rotation angle and final `v`.

You should expect two angles as output - one for vector with minimum distance and one for vector with maximum distance. Simple check should find which one is minimum

Answer (score 0):

One way to solve this that may favor ease of reading more than calculus or multiple cross products is by using [`Vector3.OrthoNormalize`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Vector3.OrthoNormalize.html).

> public static void **OrthoNormalize**(ref Vector3 **normal**, ref Vector3 **tangent**);
>   Description
>
> Makes vectors normalized and orthogonal to each other.
>
> Normalizes `normal`. Normalizes `tangent` and makes sure it is orthogonal to normal (that is, angle between them is 90 degrees).

1. Check if `o` and `t` are colinear by seeing if their cross product is `Vector3.zero`:

   ```
   if (Vector3.Cross(o,t) == Vector3.zero)
   {
       // Handle colinear situation
   }
   else 
   {
   ```
2. Otherwise, copy `o` and `t` so as to only modify the copies:

   ```
       Vector3 oCopy = o;
       Vector3 tCopy = t;
   ```
3. Use `Vector3.OrthoNormalize` using the copies, with `t`'s copy as `tangent`:

   ```
       Vector3.OrthoNormalize(ref oCopy, ref tCopy);

       Vector3 v = tCopy; // unnecessary; just included to have a variable named v
       // Use v
   }
   ```

Altogether:

```
if (Vector3.Cross(o,t) == Vector3.zero)
{
    // Handle colinear situation
}
else 
{
    Vector3 oCopy = o;
    Vector3 tCopy = t;

    Vector3.OrthoNormalize(ref oCopy, ref tCopy);

    Vector3 v = tCopy; // unnecessary; just included to have a variable named v
    // Use v
}
```