# In Unity Calculate Points a Given Distance Perpendicular to a Line at Angles on a Circle

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I crafted a model to illustrate what I am trying to calculate. Given a line (vector) between two anchor points, I want to place one or more game objects a certain distance tangential to the midpoint of that vector and at designated angles (radians?) along a circle that is perpendicular to the vector.

In this illustration, an imaginary circle is placed at midpoint and perpendicular to the line between Anchor 1 and Anchor 2. I want to calculate the Vector3 positions of three points (P1, P2, and P3). The intent is to place objects at each of those points. The entire assembly will a gameobject that can rotate in space. (There will be a single game object with each object a child.)

[image]

I have scoured StackOverflow and the Unity communities and cannot find examples that help me make those three placements.

Any ideas?

Comment: What exactly are the inputs? `Vector3 Anchor1;` and `Vector3 Anchor2;` and radius `float r;`?

Comment: I would have exactly those inputs. I have experimented with the `RotateAround(Vector3 point, Vector3 axis, float angle)` among other attempts. The difficulty is placing the points on an imaginary circle of `r` radius and `n` degrees offset from top center.

Comment: My trigonometry is is lacking.

Comment: I can place a single object at a specified distance from the mid-point. It's revolving/orbiting other objects around the same point in an imaginary plane perpendicular to that anchor line.

Comment: So, basically: you want to instantiate N gameObjects at equidistant points on a circle, then transform the circle so that it's centered at your line segment's midpoint and rotated so that its plane is perpendicular to the line segment? If you can already do that with one object (as you stated), doing it with the root of a sub-hierarchy is the same thing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of trig, consider vector math and quaternions. Use cross products to find the 0 angle offset and quaternions to rotate it according to the angle. See comments for explanation.

```
public void PlaceObjects(Transform anchor1, Transform anchor2, float r, 
        List<Transform> objs, List<float> angles)
{
    // lists must be non-null and same size
    Debug.Assert(objs != null);
    Debug.Assert(angles != null);
    Debug.Assert(objs.Count == angles.Count);
 
    // Find midpoint and axis of rotation   
    Vector3 midpoint = 0.5f * (anchor1.position + anchor2.position);
    Vector3 axis = (anchor2.position - anchor1.position).normalized;

    // What direction should the the "zero" offset be based on? 
    // Base it on the local up of the "assembly parent" this script is attached to?
    // or Vector3.up if "0 angle" should approximate world up?
    Vector3 upDirection = transform.up;

    // Of directions perpendicular to the axis find the closest to upDirection
    // See https://stackoverflow.com/a/57698547/1092820 for more information
    Vector3 axisRight = Vector3.Cross(upDirection, axis);

    if (axisRight == Vector3.zero) 
    {
        // upDirection & axis are colinear, no unique "up-ish" exists.
        // Just give up and don't move anything.
        return;
    }

    Vector3 zeroOffsetDir = Vector3.Cross(axis, axisRight);

    for (int i = 0 ; i < objs.Count ; i++)
    {
        Transform obj = objs[i];
        float angle = angles[i];
 
        // Find a rotation that describes how to rotate a "0 angle" offset into the one 
        // the current object needs
        Quaternion rot = Quaternion.AngleAxis(angle, axis); 
     
        // Find the offset by rotating the "zero" offset, then extending it by the radius
        Vector3 offset = r * (rot * zeroOffsetDir);

        // Set the object's position based on its offset and the location of the midpoint
        obj.position = midpoint + offset;

        // Optionally, set the object's rotation based on its current forward and the new up:
        // obj.rotation = Quaternion.LookRotation(obj.forward, offset);
    }
}
```

Comment: Brilliant! Exactly what I needed. I'd experimented with various combinations of Vector3 functions for three weeks and couldn't get what I wanted, so I didn't have any code samples to share and was having a hard time describing it (which is probably why someone down-voted my post as not showing effort or research). But since it was hard to describe, I modeled it out in SketchUp instead and hoped the picture would convey the objective. I'm glad you could make sense of my model.

Comment: I had to make one change to make your solution work and that was to comment out the check whether `axisRight == Vector3.zero`. At run time this always returned true and execution did not proceed further.

Comment: I also added a couple of caching variables to skip the Update() call if the anchors haven't moved.

Answer (score 0):

For those interested, here's my Component adaptation of @Ruzihm's solution. The `PlaceObjectsOnCirclePerpendicularToVectorLine` component is placed on an empty game object.

```
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class PlaceObjectsOnCirclePerpendicularToVectorLine : MonoBehaviour
{
    // Adapted from https://stackoverflow.com/a/63308834/13052746, by Ruzihm.

    public Transform anchor1;
    public Transform anchor2;
    public float radius;
    public List<Transform> objs;
    public List<float> angles;

    private Vector3 anchor1PriorPosition;
    private Vector3 anchor2PriorPosition;

    // Start is called before the first frame update
    void Start()
    {
        PlaceObjects(
            anchor1,
            anchor2,
            radius,
            objs,
            angles);
    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update()
    {
        PlaceObjects(
            anchor1,
            anchor2,
            radius,
            objs,
            angles);
    }

    public void PlaceObjects(
        Transform anchor1, 
        Transform anchor2, 
        float radius,
        List<Transform> objs, 
        List<float> angles)
    {

        if (anchor1PriorPosition == anchor1.position &&
            anchor2PriorPosition == anchor2.position)
        {
            // The anchors haven't moved.
            return;
        } else
        {
            anchor1PriorPosition = anchor1.position;
            anchor2PriorPosition = anchor2.position;
        }

        // lists must be non-null and same size
        Debug.Assert(objs != null);
        Debug.Assert(angles != null);
        Debug.Assert(objs.Count == angles.Count);

        // Find midpoint and axis of rotation   
        Vector3 midpoint = 0.5f * (anchor1.position + anchor2.position);
        Vector3 axis = (anchor2.position - anchor1.position).normalized;

        // What direction should the the "zero" offset be based on? 
        // Base it on the local up of the "assembly parent" this script is attached to?
        // or Vector3.up if "0 angle" should approximate world up?
        Vector3 upDirection = transform.up;

        // Of directions perpendicular to the axis find the closest to upDirection
        // See https://stackoverflow.com/a/57698547/1092820 for more information
        Vector3 axisRight = Vector3.Cross(upDirection, axis);

        //if (axisRight == Vector3.zero)
        //{
        //    // upDirection & axis are colinear, no unique "up-ish" exists.
        //    // Just give up and don't move anything.
        //    return;
        //}

        Vector3 zeroOffsetDir = Vector3.Cross(axis, axisRight);

        for (int i = 0; i < objs.Count; i++)
        {
            Transform obj = objs[i];
            float angle = angles[i];

            // Find a rotation that describes how to rotate a "0 angle" offset into the one 
            // the current object needs
            Quaternion rot = Quaternion.AngleAxis(angle, axis);

            // Find the offset by rotating the "zero" offset, then extending it by the radius
            Vector3 offset = radius * (rot * zeroOffsetDir);

            // Set the object's position based on its offset and the location of the midpoint
            obj.position = midpoint + offset;
        }
    }
}
```

Here's what it looks like in the Scene view:
[image: Scene view of three objects placed at equidistant angles on a circle perpendicular to a line]

And here's what the component looks like in the inspector:
[image: Component properties in the Inspector]

Again, brilliant, @Ruzihm! Exactly what I wanted!

Comment: thanks! just fyi since you took the `if (axisRight == Vector3.zero)` check out, if the axis and `upDirection` are colinear, then everything will be placed directly onto the axis. Depending on how `anchor1` and `anchor2` might be guaranteed to be positioned compared to `transform.up`, that might be impossible, in which case it would be not an issue. Anyway, just letting you know ;)